# How was this Eclipse view made?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image: Eclipse plugin view]

I'm looking in developing a plugin For Eclipse that will add a new context menu and when clicked a dialog will pop up and users will be able to select from a list of thing to install.
I would like my dialog to have the same look and feel of the attached screen shoot (from eclipse when you edit a new plugin).

So my question is: Any idea how this interface was made? It is HTML and if so how can this be done? Or are this custom Swing controls, or something like this?
I'm new to Java so i might not ask the question properly, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT for the UI.

Comment: Maybe you should look at some RCP tutorials. The ones at [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html) are pretty good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This multipage editor contains elements created with [Eclipse Forms](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html) that is based on SWT.

Comment: Perfect. Seems exactly like what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This editor is probably done using a `MultiPageEditorPart`, though I can not find the exact class. (*Update:* [Found the class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/IDE-Eclipse/Eclipse-plug-in-development/org/eclipse/pde/internal/ui/editor/plugin/ManifestEditor.java.htm), though I don't think it will help much...)

To make such an editor on your own, you should start by creating a *New Plugin Project* using the *Plugin with multi-page editor* template.  Maybe this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/eclipseplugindevelopment/11-editors) helps you getting started.

Note however, that this will be an *Editor* (placed in the centre of the Eclipse workbench and used for editing some file), and neither a *View* (placed at the side, providing some additional functionality) nor a Dialog. Instead, you might want to create a multi-page *Wizard*, featuring one page for each of the tabs. This would correspond more to the general look-and-feel of Eclipse. The above link provides some hints on this, as well.